# Surface partition by line created by datum points (abaqus python script)

Tags: python, abaqus

In a Python script, I am trying to partition a surface with a line that I have to build using the datum points (not by coordinates of the points) previously created on the part surface. Here's example of code:

```
s = m.ConstrainedSketch(gridSpacing=2.2, name='__profile__', sheetSize=88.27, transform=p.MakeSketchTransform(sketchPlane=p.faces[0], sketchPlaneSide=SIDE1, sketchUpEdge=p.edges[1], sketchOrientation=RIGHT, origin=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)))
p.projectReferencesOntoSketch(filter=COPLANAR_EDGES, sketch=s)
s.Line(point1=p.datums[43], point2=p.datums[44])
p.PartitionFaceBySketch(faces=p.faces[0:1]+p.faces[0:1], sketch=s, sketchUpEdge=p.edges[1])
del s
```

but got error: " found DatumPoint, expecting tuple". Please help

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution to the problem: should use datum location (coordinates) specified by the pointOn . I apologize for bothering. Have a good one.